# appMobi XDK simulated device orientation change

Tags: appmobi

Is the content rendered in appMobi's device emulator supposed to respond (in the emulator) to simulated orientation changes?  Mine doesn't, and I'm wondering if that's a problem with my installation or whether that level of sophistication is not (yet) available in the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XDK should throw an "appMobi.device.orientation.change" Javascript event when the simulated orientation changes.  Any other rendering changes would depend on how your HTML is structured.  Do you see that event?

Make sure to use the "Rotate Orientation" button rather than simply rotating the application using the accelerometer controls.
  [image]

Comment: thanks for the response; I am just beginning to look at the toolkit (downloaded a couple of days ago), and have the Hello World [beep, vibrate, bark, play dead] opened in the emulator (3.4.0 build 407); located below the Reload App button there is button whose tooltip says "Rotate" but it does not resemble the button above. It has no effect when clicked. I am in iPad emulation.

Comment: Good question!  The Hello World sample's rotate button is actually locked because of two commands in the onDeviceReady function:          `AppMobi.device.setRotateOrientation("portrait"); ` and
        `AppMobi.device.setAutoRotate(false);`.  If you remove those two lines (or at least the second one) you should be able to simulate a rotation.